# Do motherboards still need washers?

Tags: motherboard

Do I still need to use washers for a motherboard? I've just recently gotten my hands on an MSI 770-G45, and I noticed the spots on the board where the screws are supposed to go have no metal around them, like the other boards I've worked with, see [here](http://www.msi.com/index.php?func=proddesc&maincat_no=1&prod_no=1937). The case I've gotten came with MB screws, but do I still need to get the washers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No Washers needed,** use the screws (with button head) that came with the motherboard. It should be enough. By the way if you want you could put those red thin washers but as they didn't come with the motherboard. I don't think its necessary. Make sure you don't over-tighten the screws.

Comment: Hmmm, that website was last updated April 17, 2001... :-)

Comment: Yeah know but still provides useful content

Comment: 9 year old technology articles are probably not as relevant as they should be, @subanki...

Comment: unless you have actually installed a motherboard without washers - don't recommend it from a 9 year old site.

Comment: hey I didn't refer that site , I just found an article interesting there and thought it might come handy . So instead of copy pasting here I just put the link here. And Besides I removed that link after JNK's comment. Also I have installed many motherboards without washers. And you don't need washers even if you don't have that metal surrounding around the screw holes. And also I didn't put this answer here without a thorough google search

Comment: Are you guys talking about the website I linked to? Because I linked that website b/c it has an exact picture of the screw holes I'm talking about...

Comment: @comjuliox, no, we're referring to a site that was mentioned [in a previous revision of this very answer](http://superuser.com/posts/187655/revisions).

Answer (score 2):

When there are screw holes without surrounding metal I use felt washers between the board and the mounting post. That removes any possibility of inadvertently damaging the board by over-tightening.

Comment: Where, I think, damaging is not only limited to the place where the screws touch the board, but also (or maybe even more important) to ensure the board is not somehow bent (or: twisted? I don't know the English word) due to tension when the housing is not 100% perfect.